# Allure for Jenkins on OSX - getting "Error: Could not find or load main class ru.yandex.qatools.allure.CommandLine"

Tags: macos, jenkins, permissions, allure

I'm trying to set up [Allure reporting](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki) on my local Jenkins instance (Mac OS X 10.10.5),  but get the build failing due to Allure's report generation failure:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ru.yandex.qatools.allure.CommandLine
Build step 'Allure Report' marked build as failure
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE

testGroups 
:clean 
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE 
:processResources UP-TO-DATE 
:classes JP-TO-DATE 
:compileTestJavallote: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 

:processTestResources 
:testClasses 
:testGroupsobjc[90296]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. 
[AppClassLoader@7f31245a] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has 
not been specified 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL 
Total time: 19.406 secs 

This build could be faster, please consider using the Cradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.11/userguide/gradle_daemon.html  Build step 'Invoke Cradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS 
[workspace] $ /usr/local/Cellar/allure-commandline/1.4.23/bin/allure generate "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/addressbook-tests-windows/workspace/addressbook-tests-windows/build/allure-results" "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/addressbook-tests-windows/workspace/allure3853987377017667378.tmp/environment" -o "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/addressbook-tests-windows/workspace/allure3853987377017667378.tmp/allure-report" Error: Could not find or load main class ru.yandex.qatools.allure.CommandLine Build step 'Allure Report' marked build as failure Recording test results 
Finished: FAILURE
```

When I build from console, the report is being generated, all works fine.

Maybe someone has had this problem too and knows how to solve it?